# Textbox not storing the information and others do if not null of empty

Tags: c#, if-statement, textbox, controls

I'm trying to make that theirs a check if a textbox is empty, it wont pass the information on multiple textboxes on a button press, example:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(t => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t.Text)))
        {
             // what can i put here to exclude multiple
        }
        else
        {
            //if any of thouse are empty i dont want them to do this but if they are not empty i do want
            lablCinnamonset.Text = textBox1.Text; 
            lablMallardset.Text = textBox2.Text;
            lablAxisdeerSet.Text = textBox3.Text;
            lablBlackbuckSet.Text = textBox4.Text;
            lablMuledeerSet.Text = textBox5.Text;
            lablReddeerSet.Text = textBox6.Text;
            lablPumaSet.Text = textBox7.Text;
            lablWaterbuffaloSet.Text = textBox8.Text;
            lablJackrabbitSet.Text = textBox9.Text;
            lablCoyoteSet.Text = textBox10.Text;
            lablWhitetailSet.Text = textBox11.Text;
            lablBlacktailSet.Text = textBox12.Text;
            lablBlackbearSet.Text = textBox13.Text;
            lablRooseveltSet.Text = textBox14.Text;
            lablMooseSet.Text = textBox15.Text;
        }
```

I don't want to do, a if statement for each textbox, it has to be a better way.

Thank you guys

Comment: So let's, say, `textBox5.Text` is *empty*. Do you want to skip `lablMuledeerSet.Text = textBox5.Text;` *only* or do you want to skip *all* assignments?

Comment: i just want to skip that one box exactly like you said:
if `textbox5.text` is empty i want to skip `lablMuledeerSet.Text= textbox5.Text;`

Thank you for the fast reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't just *extract a method*?

```
  private static void AssignIfNotEmpty(Control target, Control source) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source.Text))
      target.Text = source.Text;
  }
```

Then use it

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  AssignIfNotEmpty(lablCinnamonset, textBox1); 
  AssignIfNotEmpty(lablMallardset, textBox2);
  AssignIfNotEmpty(lablAxisdeerSet, textBox3);
  AssignIfNotEmpty(lablBlackbuckSet, textBox4);
  AssignIfNotEmpty(lablMuledeerSet, textBox5);
  AssignIfNotEmpty(lablReddeerSet, textBox6);
  AssignIfNotEmpty(lablPumaSet, textBox7);
  AssignIfNotEmpty(lablWaterbuffaloSet, textBox8);
  AssignIfNotEmpty(lablJackrabbitSet, textBox9);
  AssignIfNotEmpty(lablCoyoteSet, textBox10);
  AssignIfNotEmpty(lablWhitetailSet, textBox11);
  AssignIfNotEmpty(lablBlacktailSet, textBox12);
  AssignIfNotEmpty(lablBlackbearSet, textBox13);
  AssignIfNotEmpty(lablRooseveltSet, textBox14);
  AssignIfNotEmpty(lablMooseSet, textBox15);
}
```

You may want to *organize* your controls e.g.

```
public partial class MyForm : Form {
  private Dictionary<Label, TextBox> m_Correspondence = 
    new Dictionary<Label, TextBox>();

  public MyForm() {
    InitializeComponent();

    m_Correspondence.Add(lablCinnamonset, textBox1);
    m_Correspondence.Add(lablMallardset, textBox2);
    ...
    m_Correspondence.Add(lablMooseSet, textBox15);
  }
```

In this case `button1_Click` will be very simple:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  foreach (var pair in m_Correspondence)
    AssignIfNotEmpty(pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

Comment: Just one more question i'm trying to create a dictionary but then i cant access the `M_Correspondence` so im guessing im dropping the `Dictionary<Label, TextBox> m_Correspondence = new Dictionary<Label, TextBox>();` in the wrong spot, can you give me a direction, first time working whit dictionaries.

Comment: @Sinesters: declare `m_Correspondence` as a `private` *field*, fill in it in the *constructor` after `InitializeComponent();`, please, see my edit

Comment: Thank you this, changed my way of coding , glad you took the time to give me a hand.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you can change the names of various "labl..." with something like "labl1", "labl2" or mapping them in some way (maybe using a Dictionary), then you can use the
FindName function.
Example:

```
for(int i=1; i<16; i++){
   if( (TextBox)this.FindName("textBox" + i.ToString()).Text != ""){
       //Here you can do what you want
   }
}
```

Reference here: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname?view=netframework-4.8